# OutOfMemoryError in Android Tests

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robotium

I have a lot of test for Android application and when I run them separately It is OK. But if I start All tests, testing falls with OutOfMemoryError after 10-15 minutes.

I use Robotium test system and Genymotion emulator.

```
com.my.package.AnyTest:INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
```

Comment: without seeing the actual code that causes this ....

Comment: do you tried with emulator with different RAM size?

Comment: Code is ordinary Android tests and looks like 
  `public class TestClass extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<OneOfActivity> {
  
  protected Solo solo;
  
  @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }
  @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
  }
  
  public void testDoSomething(){
    solo.waitForText(...);
  }
  }`

Comment: @Sree I tried to use more RAM, but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is very simple, I hope Nobody will never spend a lot of time to solve this problem

You should call `super.tearDown();` in tearDown() method of all inherited classes. If you don't do it, created activities will not be deleted.